# What do I need to get SSL sockets (SslRMIServerSocketFactory/SslRMIClientSocketFactory)?

Tags: security, authentication, ssl, rmi

Hy, basically I want to get SslRMIServerSocketFactory/SslRMIClientSocketFactory to secure my RMI calls. What is the common way to get these when client authentication is also necessary (keystores, certificates, ..)? What do I need to generate/ship?

**edit:** I successfully secured the communication now with RMI with server and client authentication and self-signed certificates. This works now on my machine. I submitted the certificates, truststores and keystores to the repository, but it won't work on other machines.
It was suggested that the migration broke the keystore, but I can't figure out why? Does anyone have an idea?
**edit:** Here is the complete stacktrace

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: localhost; nested exception is: 
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)

java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: localhost; nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)  at
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:614)  at
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198) at
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184) at 
sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)  at 
sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)  at 
com.uc4.webui.sla.monitoring.SLAMonitoringAccessService.<init>(SLAMonitoringAccessService.java:40) at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)  at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)  at 
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)  at 
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.createInstance(ServiceComponent.java:457) at 
    org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.createInstance(ServiceComponentProp.java:264) at 
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:325) at 
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588) at 
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196) at 
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:441) at 
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:213) at 
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:800) at 
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:767) at 
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)  at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: 
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)  at 
javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:179) at 
javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:192) at 
javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(SslRMIClientSocketFactory.java:105) at 
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595
)  ... 22 more Caused by: 
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)  at 
java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1245)  at 
sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:220)  at 
sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:147)  at 
javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:125)  at 
javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:68)  at 
javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:102)  at 
javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory.getDefaultClientSocketFactory(SslRMIClientSocketFactory.java:192) at 
javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(SslRMIClientSocketFactory.java:102) ... 23 more Caused by: 
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format  at 
sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:633)  at 
sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:38) at 
java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)  at 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.getDefaultKeyManager(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:150) at 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.<init>(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:40) at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)  at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)  at 
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)  at 
java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1221)  ... 30 more
```

My platform is Windows 7 and

```
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

Here are the keytool command which I used for the generation:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -validity 3650 -keystore bundlekeystore.jks
keytool -export -keystore bundlekeystore.jks -rfc -file bundlecertificate.cer
keytool -import -file standalonecertificate.cer -keystore truststore.jks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your need to export your remote objects using instances of each of those classes, configured appropriately according to your special requirements about enabled protocols and cipher suites if any.
2. Your server needs a private key and signed certificate in its keystore.
3. If it's a self-signed certificate, it needs to be exported from there and imported into the client's truststore.
4. Your client needs a private key and signed certificate in its keystore.
5. If it's a self-signed certificate, it needs to be exported from there and imported into the servers's truststore.
6. If the certificates are signed by a recognized CA you can omit the parts involving truststores.
7. If your client has any special requirements about protocols or cipher suites it needs to set the system properties described for [SslRMIClientSocketFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/rmi/ssl/SslRMIClientSocketFactory.html).
8. If you also want a secure Registry you have to take several additional steps which I will post here if you ask, but they are fairly obvious if you have a look at the LocateRegistry.createRegistry()/getRegistry() overloads that take socket factory parameters.

Comment: thx for another high-quality answer EJP, but I still can not get it running (only considering client auth). I generated a keystore, made it to a certificate, imported this certificate to a trustore, and set System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "./server/truststore.jks"), what indeed adds the certificate in the debug console. At the client I load theinitial keystore, initialize the SSLContext. But how can I extract an SslRmiClientSocketFactory from it?

Comment: please consider to take a look at my follow up question ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707986/why-is-my-rmi-ssl-client-authentication-not-working

Comment: @WorstCase you can't do any of that. The client SSF is downloaded from the server, that's why you specify it when exporting, and it uses the default SSLContext (unless you've subclassed it, which you can do, which is a security breach IMO). All you can do at the client is specify system properties. And can we deal with it all here please? It's the same issue.

Comment: @WorstCase what platform is that new code running on? and what JDK? java -version output? and what is the complete stack trace?

Comment: @WorstCase 'java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format'. So the keystore is corrupt.

Comment: that was the hint I needed! The keystore was submitted to the repository in Unicode, which messed things up. THX

Comment: @WorstCase That 'hint' has been there in the stacktrace all the time.